# Perl regular expression question

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to use Perl split function on comma delimited lines and capture only two or more words between the comma delimited into an array. Single words are not needed.

For example, this line -->> aaa, ccc ddd, eee, fff ggg uuu, 
I only want, `ccc ddd and fff ggg uuu`

```
while(<FH>)
{
   @ = split(/,/);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Added " aaa," protection, and ", ," protection as well.

```
$line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # or you get false positives 
my @multiword = grep {/\s/} split /\s*,[,\s]*/, $line;
```

The split will eat up all space around commas, so anything in the array that contains a space is a multi-word.

Comment: its not doing what i want, i want the individual mulit-words, not the whole line that contains single and multi-words...

Comment: thanks Dallaylaen for the change and not being clear. Its working as needed. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

demo script:

```
my @data = (
     'aaa, ccc ddd, eee, fff ggg uuu'
   , ' aaa bbb ,ccc,eee,fff ggg uuu '
   , 'aaa,ccc,eee,fff'
);
for my $line (@data) {
  printf "|%s| ==> \n", $line;
  $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
  my @cut = grep { / / } split( /\s*,\s*/, $line );
  printf "|%s|\n\n", join( '|', @cut );
}
```

output:

```
|aaa, ccc ddd, eee, fff ggg uuu| ==>
|ccc ddd|fff ggg uuu|

| aaa bbb ,ccc,eee,fff ggg uuu | ==>
|aaa bbb|fff ggg uuu|

|aaa,ccc,eee,fff| ==>
||
```

less terse than Dallaylaen's solution, but may make it easy to check for/handle special cases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out \s* at the end and beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:

> (undef, undef, @parsedvalues) = split /,/

You esentialy throw away first two values you get from split.